# Unable to send notification on android using Azure Notification Hub

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to send a notification to an android device using Azure Notification Hub.

I have followed the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started).

The android emulator can register to the hub as shown in the screenshot but when I am trying to send a test message I am getting the following error:

```
The Push Notification System handle for the registration is invalid
```

[image: screenshot]

Also the count it zero??? Is it registered or not?

Google has update the Firebase API so I have updated my code from in sample

```
String FCM_token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

to

```
String FCM_token = InstanceID.getInstance(this).getToken(NotificationSettings.SenderId, "RECEIVE");
```

I am not sure what the second argument should be. [Firebase documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID.html#getToken(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) suggests it should be scope.

Can't figure out what is causing this to fail. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try with `INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE`?

```
InstanceID.getInstance(this).getToken(NotificationSettings.SenderId, GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null)
```

Comment: Thank you Sateesh!